# LI's with variable pixel/% widths not followed in full width of container

Tags: html, css

I'm working with the following code which creates a series of boxes as **`<UL><LI>`** tags. The splits are separate `<LI>`s with a background img containing the arrows. What needs to happen is that if you resize, the arrow-LI size must **not** change, but the data-LI size should accommodate and shrink accordingly. To accomplish this, the arrow-LI widths are specified in **px**, and the data-LI in **%**. At all times, the entire box bar must be 1-line.

[image]

This should work, but I see that if I resize, the last box is brought out to a 2nd line, and at some point later the next-to-last box will be lowered to a 2nd line too. The text does shrink, but it should auto-shrink even more to satisfy any reasonable browser width, while the arrow LIs are fixed.

[image]

Some text e.g. "Reference Letter Deadline" did shrink, but not enough to keep everything on 1 line.

[image]

Code:

```
    <ul class="arrowDateBoxes dateLists">
        <li class="arrowDateBox1">
            <div class="arrowDateBoxContent">Application Cycle Opens</div>
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox1Arrow">
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox2">
            <div class="arrowDateBoxContent">Application Deadline</div>
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox2Arrow">
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox1">
            <div class="arrowDateBoxContent">Reference Letter Deadline</div>
        </li>   
        <li class="arrowDateBox1Arrow">
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox2">
            <div class="arrowDateBoxContent">Selections for Program Interviews</div>
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox2Arrow">
        </li>   
        <li class="arrowDateBox1">
            <div class="arrowDateBoxContent">Interviews</div>
        </li>       
        <li class="arrowDateBox1Arrow">
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox2">
            <div class="arrowDateBoxContent">Offer Acceptance Deadline Date</div>
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox2Arrow">
        </li>
        <li class="arrowDateBox1">
            <div class="arrowDateBoxContent">ICRC Term Begins</div>
        </li>
```

CSS

```
/* Generally for all boxes */
ul.arrowDateBoxes li { 
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Bi-color: 
   data boxes (arrowDateBoxN), width as % to be flexible, and 
   arrow boxes (arrowDateBoxNArrow), width as px to be fixed */
/* ----------------- */
.arrowDateBox1 {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    color: #143A66;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 57px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.arrowDateBox1Arrow {
    background-image: url('../images/menuarrow-split1.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 30.5px;
    height: 57px;
}   

.arrowDateBox2 {
    background-color: #A9CDF1;
    color: #143A66;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 57px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.arrowDateBox2Arrow {
    background-image: url('../images/menuarrow-split2.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 30.5px;
    height: 57px;
}
```

**Per request, the SVGs (bi-colored arrow splits):**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30.541" height="57.001" viewBox="0 0 30.541 57.001">
  <g id="Group_225" data-name="Group 225" transform="translate(-312.858 -383.001)">
    <path id="Polygon_30" data-name="Polygon 30" d="M28.5,0,57,18.143H0Z" transform="translate(331.001 383.002) rotate(90)" fill="#e8e8e8"/>
    <path id="Subtraction_11" data-name="Subtraction 11" d="M18.4,57H0L18.142,28.5,0,0H18.4Z" transform="translate(325 383.001)" fill="#a9cdf1"/>
  </g>
</svg>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30.541" height="57.001" viewBox="0 0 30.541 57.001">
  <g id="Group_225" data-name="Group 225" transform="translate(-312.858 -383.001)">
    <path id="Polygon_30" data-name="Polygon 30" d="M28.5,0,57,18.143H0Z" transform="translate(331.001 383.002) rotate(90)" fill="#a9cdf1"/>
    <path id="Subtraction_11" data-name="Subtraction 11" d="M18.4,57H0L18.142,28.5,0,0H18.4Z" transform="translate(325 383.001)" fill="#e8e8e8"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ul to display:flex. It'll keep it all on one line. You can also probably cut out a fair amount of markup by using the ::after pseudo element for your arrows. Fire over the svg (or provide a link to it) and I'll have a look.

```
    ul.arrowDateBoxes {
      display:flex;
    }

    /* Generally for all boxes */
    ul.arrowDateBoxes li {
      list-style-type: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* Bi-color: 
   data boxes (arrowDateBoxN), width as % to be flexible, and 
   arrow boxes (arrowDateBoxNArrow), width as px to be fixed */
    /* ----------------- */
    .arrowDateBox1 {
      background-color: #E8E8E8;
      color: #143A66;
      width: 12.5%;
      height: 57px;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .arrowDateBox1Arrow {
      background-image: url('../images/menuarrow-split1.svg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 30.5px;
      height: 57px;
    }

    .arrowDateBox2 {
      background-color: #A9CDF1;
      color: #143A66;
      width: 12.5%;
      height: 57px;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .arrowDateBox2Arrow {
      background-image: url('../images/menuarrow-split2.svg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 30.5px;
      height: 57px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked wit display:flex !!!

Comment: Great! Post up that svg and I'll see if I can optimise the markup too :-)

Comment: Now added to OP.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated this so you only need `li` elements

css

```
.arrowDateBoxes {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.arrowDateBoxes>li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 57px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 29px;
}

.arrowDateBoxes>li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  color: #143A66;
}

.arrowDateBoxes li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #A9CDF1;
  color: #143A66;
}

.arrowDateBoxes>li::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 1px);
  content: '';
  width: 30.5px;
  height: 57px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.arrowDateBoxes li:nth-child(odd)::before {
  background-image: url('menuarrow-split1.svg');
}

.arrowDateBoxes li:nth-child(even)::before {
  background-image: url('menuarrow-split2.svg');
}
```

and html

```
  <ul class="arrowDateBoxes">
    <li>
      Application Cycle Opens
    </li>
    <li>
      Application Deadline
    </li>
    <li>
      Reference Letter Deadline
    </li>
    <li>
      Selections for Program Interviews
    </li>
    <li>
      Interviews
    </li>
    <li>
      Offer Acceptance Deadline Date
    </li>
    <li>
      ICRC Term Begins
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I'm not 100% satisfied with it as setting overflow-y: hidden doesn't work as it causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear but gives you the general idea.

Comment: don't add multiple answers, edit your the other one